# SSH mysteriously blocked

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn

My SSH server is at work behind the university firewall.

I connect to my university VPN and have always been able to SSH into it. Recently I used VSCode to remote work on it via SSH. The connection dropped a few times and I cannot log in anymore. Even ping does not return anything.

Here is the strange thing: If I VPN in, then SSH into my second workstation at work, and then from that SSH into the original workstation it works.

So it looks like my IP is being blocked by the workstation. But I checked:

```
sudo iptables -L INPUT -v -n | less
```

and it shows:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 401K packets, 599M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
(END)
```

So it is not my workstation? What is happening? Anything else I can check?

---

**Update**

Output of ssh -vvv:

```
>>ssh -vvv dorien@172.18.2.28

OpenSSH_9.3p2, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for 172.18.2.28
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 172.18.2.28 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 172.18.2.28 [172.18.2.28] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: connect to address 172.18.2.28 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 172.18.2.28 port 22: Operation timed out
```

---

**Update 2**

Checking `sudo vi +26 /etc/ssh/sshd_config`. The only uncommented lines are:

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
Port 22
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
usePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Folder `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d` is empty.

Checking `tail /var/log/auth.log`:

```
Nov 14 15:16:15 COMP sshd[113124]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user dorien by (uid=0)
Nov 14 15:16:15 COMP systemd-logind[756]: New session 191 of user dorien.
Nov 14 15:16:28 COMP sudo:   dorien : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/dorien ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/vi +26 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Nov 14 15:16:28 COMP sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by dorien(uid=0)
Nov 14 15:17:01 COMP CRON[113225]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 14 15:17:01 COMP CRON[113225]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 14 15:18:27 COMP sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 14 15:19:23 COMP sudo:   dorien : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ls
Nov 14 15:19:23 COMP sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by dorien(uid=0)
Nov 14 15:19:23 COMP sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

This doesn't register the ssh login attempt I made at 15:21 which timed out.

---

**Update 3**

```
ssh -vvv -o IPQoS=none dorien@172.18.2.28
```

Outputs a timeout:

```
OpenSSH_9.3p2, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/dorien_herremans/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/dorien_herremans/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for 172.18.2.28
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 172.18.2.28 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/dorien_herremans/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/dorien_herremans/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 172.18.2.28 [172.18.2.28] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 172.18.2.28 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 172.18.2.28 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: Have you checked with the people who manage your university VPN?

Comment: How often does this happen? What happens if you wait a few hours or a day? It sounds like [Fail2Ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban) behavior; detects odd SSH behavior and then blocks you. It usually clears up after some time. I would also suggest looking at the output of `ssh -vvv` to see if it offers any clues.

Comment: I did not have fail2ban installed, just did that so doesn't have log yet. I've added the ssh -vvv output to the question. I'll ask the network team at uni as well.

Comment: Have you checked the configuration of the SSH daemon? Can you ping the host directly from the VPN? Have you looked at the logs on the host itself, when logged in via the second workstation?

Comment: Ping doesn't work. I added some more config outputs. Seems more and more like the network itself is blocking me I guess.

Comment: @dorien FWIW, Fali2Ban would be installed on the server, not the client. So you would not have it installed on your local machines. But university techs might have it installed on the servers.

Comment: Seems like the IPQoS option is not helping either. From the local network it connects well though. And I can connect to my other machines just fine.

Answer (score 0):

While I have no direct experience with this issue, a search online finds that this issue is connected to QoS (Quality of Service).

- Look at this [answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/1108187).
- As well as this [issue report on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8985#issuecomment-1347481765).

Look at this line in the `ssh -vvv` output:

```
debug3: set_sock_tos set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
```

Therefore, a solution is to run your SSH command with the `-o IPQoS=none` like this:

```
ssh -o IPQoS=none dorien@172.18.2.28
```

And see if disabling QoS clears things up.

If that works, consider adding this config to `~/.ssh/config` to make the setting more permanent for all hosts:

```
Host *
  IPQoS=none
```

Or make it specific to the server that you are having issues with:

```
Host 172.18.2.28
  IPQoS=none
```

Comment: I tried this, but still got: ssh: connect to host 172.18.2.28 port 22: Operation timed out. Also added new -vvv to question.

Comment: Crap! At least I tried! I would bring this up with your university techs; nothing makes sense past that.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it though! They are checking but this always takes a few days...

Comment: University techs cannot find anything in the network. It remains a mystery...